# Sanitize and data validation with apply_filters() function

Tags: filters, validation, sanitization, escaping

Should we sanitize and validate the **`apply_filters()`** like the examples below?

1. `absint( apply_filters( 'slug_excerpt_length', 35 ) );`
2. `wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'slug_excerpt_more', '&hellip;' ) );`
3. `esc_url( apply_filters( 'slug_login_url', home_url( '/' ) ) );`

I am asking this question, cause I have never seen this before. Actually we add some validation to prevent breaking something when the user adds something wrong in the child-theme.

I wonder what you think about it.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

There's some confusion here, because not all of these are validation, there are 2 others that are necessary to understand what's appropriate:

- validation
- sanitisation
- escaping

#### Sanitisation

**Sanitisation makes things clean and well formed**

This cleans up the data, e.g. trimming trailing spaces, removing letters in a number field, making an all lowercase field all lowercase, etc

> E.g. The user entered `" Banana    "`, so turn it into `"Banana"`

Sanitisation is the first thing that should happen to **input** that comes from somewhere else, e.g. when processing a form, sanitise the data before doing anything with it. The same of any data that comes from a remote connection etc

Popular sanitising methods include:

- stripping out HTML or particular tags via `wp_kses` `wp_strip_all_tags` etc
- Removing ranges of characters, such as non-numeric characters, or punctuation
- Trimming trailing characters such as spaces etc
- Applying bounds such as restricting values to within a range ( this could instead be implemented as a validation check )

#### Validation

**Validation checks if things are valid**

Validation checks that the phone number the user entered is actually a phone number. It's a `true` or `false` check.

> E.g. Is the fruit the user chose actually a fruit?

This should be done on **input** after sanitising, and if validation fails, abort, popular methods of validation include:

- functions like `is_numeric` etc
- regular expressions, useful for things like phone numbers or URLs, things that have an expected format
- checking roles and capabilities to verify the user actually has the ability to do the intended action
- nonce checks
- whitelists of predefined allowed values
- checking values sit within valid ranges, e.g. nobody has a 200 character long telephone number, nor would somebody live in house number `-2000000`

#### Escaping

**Escaping makes values safe for output, and enforces assumptions**

Escape late, escape often.

Escaping isn't talked about much, but imagine it using the fruit example from above. Escaping is like a conveyor belt with a fruit shaped cut out. You always get something fruit shaped at the end. If a fruit passes through, it's untouched, but if a malicious actor goes through, a mangled but safe fruit shaped version pops out the end.

Escaping is therefore all about enforcing assumptions. E.g. in an `<a>` tag, the `href` attribute should contain a URL. But this might not be the case, escaping allows us to swap the "should contain" to a "will always contain", providing us a guarantee. This prevents somebody starting their URL with `"/>` and inserting arbitary HTML.

Escaping should always be done on **output**, at the very latest point possible to ensure nothing was modified. Escaping is also context sensitive. You would use `esc_attr` to escape HTML attributes, but if it's a `href` or `src` attribute, we would use `esc_url` to indicate it's a URL we're intending to output.

#### A Note on Double Escaping and `wp_kses`

You can sanitize and validate multiple times, but you should only escape a value once. This is because double escaping can double encode values, and in some circumstances can allow content to break out of escaping.

`wp_kses_post` and `wp_kses` are also unusual in that they can be used to escape, **and** to sanitise, and can be used multiple times on a value.

#### A Note on Early Escaping

This is a near mortal sin that can almost undo everything escaping gives you. Once something has been escaped, we know it is safe and secure to output it, **but**, if we then assign it to a variable, who knows what might happen to it between escaping and output. If that variable gets modified, passed to a function, or piped through a filter, it's no longer safe, it's status is a mystery. We can escape it again but now we've double escaped, so we might have made safe data dangerous, or mangled good data.

### So About Those Filters

> Should we sanitize and validate the `apply_filters()` like the examples below?

It depends on the context

On input:

- Sanitise
- then validate
- if it's valid then proceed, else reject

On output to the browser/requests/etc:

- you can sanitise and validate once fetched from the database if you like, but the #1 priority is to escape, escape only once, and do it on the moment of output. Don't store it in a variable, that's early escaping and it's dangerous
- Escape after filtering, not before, who knows what the filter did to a known safe value, once the value is returned from the filter its safety and status are a mystery

> 1. `absint( apply_filters( 'slug_excerpt_length', 35 ) );`

Great we now know this value is definitely a number, and a positive number too. If we prefix this statement with `echo` then that's a safe escaped value. Else it's just sanitisation that's cleaned up the value.

> 2. `wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'slug_excerpt_more', '&hellip;' ) );`

Great, this is both sanitising and escaping if we immediately output it, but if we save it to a variable, it's just sanitising.

> 3. `esc_url( apply_filters( 'slug_login_url', home_url( '/' ) ) );`

This is escaping, and needs an `echo` statement. If we assign this to a variable then the escaping was for nought and we introduce a precarious situation.

If the question on the other hand is, should we double check the return values of filters? Yes, that would be wise, but overcautious. In that scenario I would expect that this would be testing for filters that aren't implemented properly, e.g. returning text where a number is expected. In that scenario, validation is the only option, escaping and sanitisation would be inappropriate.

### Exceptions

- When using `the_content` filter, pass the value through `wp_kses_post` then pass it into the filter and immediatley echo, e.g. `echo apply_filters( 'the_content', wp_kses_post( $dangerous ) );`
- In shortcodes, escape and use output buffers if you must, so that you can return a string

Comment: This is a really good explanation. I didn't expect so much information. Thank you guys. <3

Comment: Epic answer, thanks. Is it safe to do this in a function? Eg: `return esc_url( apply_filters( 'slug_login_url', home_url( '/' ) ) );` at the end of the function and then `echo myfunction()` in the template? Or should the escape be outside the function, like `echo esc_url( myfunction() )` to be fully secure?

Comment: no that would be early escaping, it would be safer to do `echo esc_url( myfunction() )`. Otherwise we have to _trust_ that `myfunction` is used correctly, and who needs _trust_ that it should be used correctly when we can guarantee it? functions that return things should either output escaped content, or be escaped themselves. If `myfunction` returned escaped HTML, we now have 2 problems: 1) we don't know how many times its been escaped and 2) who's supposed to do the escaping? How do we know if `myfunction` did it or if we should do it?