# Coding a plugin on WordPress; when should I sanitize?

Tags: plugin-development, security, sanitization

I am developing a custom plugin on WordPress for a client. Just a simple question: when I am using `update_post_meta()` and `update_user_meta()`, do I need to use the WordPress sanitization functions? I was under the impression that I don't, since the documentation says that `$meta_key` and `$meta_value` should be raw.

Are there any other instances / WordPress features in a plugin wherein I will need to sanitize my data?

Comment: It's not the same question as yours, but Tom's answer to [this question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/309233/sanitize-and-data-validation-with-apply-filters-function/309237#309237) gives a great overview of santitising and escaping, the difference between them, and when you should use them. But just regarding your question: for those functions 'raw' means un-*escaped*, not un-sanitized. Whether and what sanitisation is appropriate depends on your data and how you use it.